# Java I want to search for a binary hex value in my byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, fileinputstream

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  File inFile = null;
  if (0 < args.length) {
      inFile = new File(args[0]);
  }

    BufferedInputStream bStream = null;

    try {

        int read;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1260];
        bStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));

        while ((read = bStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
            getMarker(read);
        }
    }

 private static void getMarker(int read) {

 }
```

I'm having trouble seeing where my byte array is created and where I can access the data in the byte array.  I thought `read` would have been my byte array where I could search for my  marker in `getMarker` (probably using a long), but read is just an integer value. Is the data in my byte array in `bytes` then?  Or where can I access the actually binary values in the byte array to search?

Comment: Binary hex value ? Sounds confusing to me. Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry, when I view the value in HxD it's in hex obviously, but I'll probably search for a long.

Answer (score 2):

The `read` methods fills a part of the array you pass with data read from the file, and returns the number of bytes it read. To access the array in your `getMarker` method you have to pass it there, not just the number of bytes that were read into it. For example:

```
    while ((read = bStream.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        getMarker(read, bytes);
    }
...

 private static void getMarker(int read, byte[] bytes) {
     // data has been read into the "bytes" array into index 0 through read-1
 }
```